# Hadoop data nodes die very often

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, nfs

Our Hadoop cluster is a cluster of 5 data nodes and 2 name nodes. The traffic is actually very high and a few nodes go down very often. But they come back after a while. Some times it takes a long time, more than half an hour to come back alive.

There are few DNs with more threads than the others. Is this a configuration problem?
The data is not write intensive. MR jobs run every 20 minutes.

After running a health monitor for two days, sampled at half an hour interval, we came to know that the nodes die during disk verification which runs every 6 hours. So now the nodes die predictably. But why do they die during disk verification? Is there anyway to prevent the nodes die during the disk verification??

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logs? If so, please add those to your question.

Comment: There aren't any error messages in the logs.

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block

Answer (score 0):

[Clouedera's capacity planning](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/hadoophbase-capacity-planning/) gives an insight on this.   If you see “Bad connect ack with firstBadLink”, “Bad connect ack”, “No route to host”, or “Could not obtain block” IO exceptions under heavy loads, chances are these are due to a bad network.